# Getting NullPointerException when call get() methods from model class in Android

Tags: android

I have the following model class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Cheltuiala implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private Date data;
    private String tip;
    private float pret;

    public Cheltuiala() {

    }

    public Cheltuiala(Date data, String tip, float pret) {
        this.data = data;
        this.tip = tip;
        this.pret = pret;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getTip() {
        return tip;
    }

    public float getPret() {
        return pret;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setTip(String tip) {
        this.tip = tip;
    }

    public void setPret(float pret){
        this.pret = pret;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id:" + id + " data:" + data + " tip:" + tip + " pret:" + pret;
    }
}
```

Here is the method from the DetailsActivity that extends Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details); // legatura dintre activitate si view

    Intent intent = getIntent(); //continutul cu care s-a apelat

    final Cheltuiala cheltuiala = (Cheltuiala) intent.getSerializableExtra("cheltuiala");

    System.out.println(cheltuiala.getData());

    EditText data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
    data.setText(cheltuiala.getData().toString());

    EditText tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTip);
    System.out.println(cheltuiala);
    tip.setText(cheltuiala.getTip());

    EditText pret = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPret);
    pret.setText(String.valueOf(cheltuiala.getPret()));
}
```

When I print 'cheltuiala', I see what I want, but when I call get() methods from 'Cheltuiala' class, I got NullPointerException. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: What are you getting with this : (Cheltuiala) intent.getSerializableExtra("cheltuiala");

Comment: Comment line by line and check where are you getting NPE and where you are getting your result. And post your  logcat here.

Comment: I got NPE anywhere i called get() methods. If I comment all the lines after  'System.out.println(cheltuiala.getData());', I got exception. If I replace getData() with getTip(), or getPret(), I got the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

as you have use `toString()` method you can get `NPE` when `getData` is null. you can check `getData` that is null or not and if is not null use `.toString()`

you can use following code:

```
data.setText(cheltuiala.getData() == null ? "" : cheltuiala.getData().toString());
```

as you say when i use every get method that is null might be `data` is null. check that you have `editTextData` id in `activity_details`

Comment: Yes, but i got NullPointerException if I call any get() method.

Comment: so your object is null, did you check that?

Comment: That's the problem. My object isn't null.